# How hashset remove duplicate entries?

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

```
public class Type extends SomeObject implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer typeId;

    private String typeName;

     private String typeCode;
}
```

I am getting data from database using hibernate as Type object. Now my class do not (Nor its parent class) override equals method. SO if i insert all of Type object into a hashset it shouldn't remove duplicates but it is removing duplicate. My question is that how is it able to identify duplicates ?

Comment: it should not and never unless it finds `hashcode and equals`

Comment: how about the `SomeObject` class? is it override the method?

Comment: Conceptually it shouldn't . Does it means it is cashing values and using same object if it has multiple refrence

Comment: It does because Object has a hashCode() and a equals() method. And inside a Hibernate Session, a given entity only has a unique instance.

Comment: Parents class is not overriding Equals.

Comment: Are you adding different references of object which is referring to same object ?

Comment: Post the code where you are objects to the set

Comment: @ user3391293: What is the primary key ?

Answer (score 3):

Inside a Hibernate Session, a given entity only exists once. I.e. if you do

```
Type type1 = (Type) session.get(Type.class, 42);
Type type2 = (Type) session.get(Type.class, 42);
Type type3 = (Type) session.createQuery("select t from Type t where t.id = 42").uniqueResult();
```

then `type1`, `type2` and `type3` will all be references to a single object. Adding them all in a empty HashSet will thus lead to a HashSet of size 1, because `Object.equals()` returns true when comparing an object with itself.

Answer (score -3):

if you're class is overriding the hashcode and equals method, the overridden methods are used, or else default methods, the ones present in Object class are used. But hashcode and equals are used in HashSets, Hashmaps, etc.

For default behaviour you can refer to [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

> The **equals** method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, **this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true)**
>
> As much as is reasonably practical, the **hashCode** method defined by
>   class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (**This
>   is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the
>   object into an integer**, but this implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming language.)

Adding how does it find duplicates:

Lets look at hashing first:
Hashing is used to retrieve data quickly. Basically hash function generates an index value (this index value usually refers to a bucket that can store objects), once  this index value is generated, it searches for that object inside that particular bucket.

i'd suggest you to look into hashing once

[Hashing Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

Whenever we add to hashset, the hashcode method is used,it returns an index value, the object is stored in that bucket(the bucket corresponding to that index). **when again the same object is being added, the hashcode value will be same, so it refers to the same bucket, now since the object is already present(here equals method is used to check equality amongst objects) in that bucket, it is not added again**

```
class Data {

public Data(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}

String name;
}

public class ReadFromFile {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Data s = new Data("yo");
    HashSet<Data> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(new Data("hi"));// hi
    set.add(new Data("hi"));// hi but has a different address because a new
                            // object is created
    System.out.println("Size before adding s " + set.size());
    set.add(s);
    set.add(s);// because same object is being added, default hashcode
                // generates same value, as it uses address to generate
                // hashcode
    System.out.println("Size after adding s " + set.size());
}

}
```

output
Size before adding s 2
Size after adding s 3

Comment: the stuff i have quoted is the default behavior of hashcode and equals,methods that are used by hashset